# Compilation Error can any tell me why this error show on my site

Tags: asp.net

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'login' exists in both 'c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\33c89962\5b7b1735\assembly\dl3\2b120ec6\9b3c4686_20f5d001\App_Code.DLL' and 'c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\33c89962\5b7b1735\assembly\dl3\264080ca\7f19e285_20f5d001\App_Web_login.aspx.cdcab7d2.DLL'

Source Error:

[No relevant source lines]

Source File: App_Web_login.aspx.cdcab7d2.ak6t3ez7.0.cs    Line: 148

my site : http://www.logodesignconsultant.com/login.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have declared two times the same type (login here). If you have coded any of this two files, try changing the "login" type into another name.